# PUBG Mobile User Stats

Tags: android, pubg

I was looking for ways to get player stats for PUBG Mobile players. From their official developer website, I have seen that there is no support for player stats on Mobile platform. Here is the [link](https://developer.pubg.com/) for the official documentation. Also, I have read a few posts in PUBG developer forum that confirms this. However, I have come across this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tencent.gamehelper.intl) which is basically a game booster app for performance boost for mobile games that can actually get the stats for a signed in player in the game.

I have taken a look at the decompiled APK and from what I gathered, there are no API calls or such service that requests the data from an API service. What I am interested to know is: are there any API or third party access features that can allow me to get logged in user data for PUBG mobile players?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no official public api for pubg mobile api.

The app that you mentioned is official one by tencent so they have access to the user stats data.